# '92 Hilux moves with gear in Park

Tags: electrical, toyota, automatic-transmission, starter, hilux

This is a 1992 Toyota Hilux Surf Turbo Automatic.

Just a quick question, chasing a fault on a Hilux:

- won't start off the key
- went through all fuses, relays and wiring, replaced old bushes in starter motor and cleaned
- made up a hot-wire button and it cranks over and starts fine

Now the big question:

It rolls in Park. Can this faulty safety Park unit be stopping it from starting via the key?

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! I don't know much about the Toyota Hilux, but if it's not completely going into park, it might not be allowing the vehicle to start due to the neutral safety switch. You might be able to put it into neutral to see if it will allow you to start.

Comment: hey buddy cheers for the warm welcome,  the vehicle rolled off the tow truck in park which leads me to believe there is a fault with the neutral safety switch which ties into the whole not starting off the key issue, it can go into park as it should but no luck starting off the key in park or neutral, but will happily crank over via a hotwire button

Comment: Does the shift lever move the linkage and the lever on the transmission when selecting a gear? I’d guess that the ignition switch sends power down to the range switch then to the starter relay terminal 85. Maybe a constant ground on terminal 86 or ecm controlled if it has anti theft.